# Is it possible to insert image instead of text in text field(object) in Crystal Report by a bool value from DB

Tags: crystal-reports, textfield

In my report I have a bool field which represents status (logged or not logged). So, is it possible to insert a small picture (small icon) inside a field by true/false value from database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's how to do it:

1. Insert an image as a placeholder. As an example, I have two small 512x512 .png graphics that I frequently use for this purpose, one is called "cancel.png" and the other is called "check.png". I just randomly picked one to insert into the report.
2. Right click the graphic you just inserted → select "Format Graphic" → select the "Picture" tab → hit the "x-2" button next to "Graphic Location"
3. Here you can enter the two graphics' locations relative to the report and any logic to display them. In my report, I have:

`if {Orders.Order Amount} > 200 then "C:\Desktop\check.png"
 else "C:\Desktop\cancel.png"`

Now, the report will display the check mark graphic for each order that exceeds 200, otherwise a cancel graphic (a big "X") displays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! But I have a one more question... It works for every record. I want to know how to set NULL to image place holder in case when my value is 0. This is my preview (off course I am not showing the number on the left side): http://s25.postimg.org/ihdsu165r/Login.png So, basically, I need in else case something like NULL. Thanks.

Comment: You can just conditionally suppress the image in those instances where you don't want _any_ graphic to display.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to insert 2 images and suppress one or the other based on a formula. You can put a formula which will return true or false for Suppress check box in picture box properties dialog. The advantage will be that the images will part of the report and it will not try to find them on each run. My guess is that the images will be small and this is not going to make the report too big. Changing the path on the fly is used usually when the images are too big or you need to update them often. Keep in mind that if by any reason the path to the image is not available the report will become too slow because it will wait for the drive timeout.

Comment: +1 That's a good point. For a single, stand-alone report that won't be regularly changing graphics it's probably best to insert as an embedded object. Using a path is more useful when you've got a bunch of reports sharing graphical assets that might change over time.